# Android NDK OpenGL ES rendered graphics to Java bitmap

Tags: java, android, c, opengl-es, android-ndk

I’m troubled with retrieving bitmap out of OpenGL ES 1.0 rendering. Graphics rendering is done in Android NDK and I want to display bitmap in Android Java. I know that I have to use glReadPixels function.

I’ve tried to pass Bitmap object to NDK and modify it, as it is shown in bitmap-plasma sample from NDK, but an error is occurring: “GL_INVLID_EXCEPTION” and bitmap is untouched. I have tried combinations with ABGR bitmap, but without success. There is my code:

```
void Java_com_example_polygonmap_PolygonMapyActivity_ndkOpenGLInit( JNIEnv*  env, jobject  obj, jobject bitmap ) {
AndroidBitmapInfo info;
int ret;
GLvoid* pixs;

if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
    LOGI("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    return;
}
if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixs)) < 0) {
    LOGI("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
}
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST );
///
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport( 0, 0, 400, 400 );
glOrthof( 0.0f, (float)400, 0.0f, (float)400, -1.0f, 1.0f );
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
///
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, polygon[0]);
glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3 );
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 400, 400, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixs);
////
AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
```

I have tried another approach, by reading my own unsigned char array with glReadPixels, pass it to Java and here create bitmap from array. Now pixel read doesn't return any exception, but I got in troubles when try to parse bytearray to bitmap, so that way is also failed. Code is pretty mutch the same, but without bitmap initialization and slightly different pixel reading part:

```
jbyteArray Java_com_example_polygonmap_PolygonMapyActivity_ndkOpenGLInit( JNIEnv*  env, jobject  obj)
{
void* pixs;
unsigned char ch[256*256*4];

glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST );
///
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport( 0, 0, 256, 256 );
glOrthof( 0.0f, (float)256, 0.0f, (float)256, -1.0f, 1.0f );
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
///
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, polygon[0]);
glColor4f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3 );
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixs);
jcharArray jch = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, 256*256*4);
(*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, jch, 0 , 256*256*4, &ch);
```

Here is bytearray to bitmap Java code:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ch.toString().getBytes(), 0 , ch.toString().getBytes().length);
```

My rendering is done on GLSurfaceView with implementation in native c and it is working fine, except that bitmap import.

I would be really appreciate for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, 400, 400, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixs);
```

should be ***pix*** not ***&pix***: (no "&" - otherwise it is an address of local variable not an a pointer to the pixel data)

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, 400, 400, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixs);
```